# Hive Cross product issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hdfs

I have been receiving the following error which is causing the job to get stuck in running state for hours

> INFO  : Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[6111][bigTable=?] in task 'Reducer
>   6' is a cross product

Comment: It is not an error, just a warning. post your query as well.

Comment: since it is bit sensitive information cannot share ...but main aggregation used is cross join for joining two big tables tables